# ruby on rails find.all where and append results to different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

OK, so I have a table of data called "Projects" where I have an ID and a name.  Let's say its in the world of zillions of objects and I'm not allowed to add any relationships to it, or columns, indexes or anything like that.  I want to work with a specific set of these projects that has "TI" as the seventh and eighth digit of the name, and I want to store them in another model called TI Projects where there is an ID and name column as well, so I can create relationships, add columns, etc.

So, what I want to do is find all Projects where the 7th and 8th digit of name are TI, and then I want to insert those that are found in to the TI Projects model where name is carried over from Projects to TI Projects model.  I'm having a hard time with this, obviously.  I'm doing

```
@tiprojects = Projects.all(:conditions => { :name => %%%%%%TI% } )
@tiprojects.create
```

Comment: Indexes wouldn't help that much anyway since you're dealing with regular expressions.

Comment: In all seriousness, this sounds like the work to do this would be more efficient within your DBMS, in the form of after-INSERT actions.  What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Better solution if you want to do in Rails would be to take all values matching in array and do bulk insert. Refer https://github.com/walterhorstman/bulk-insert-active-record